# Firebase functions: RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File ... is greater than 2 GB

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Been deploying a ton w/ no problems. Made a small change and now it bonks on deploy.

I rolled back a few commits and still get same error. Tried deploying only 1 function, same issue. Deleted a bunch of log files, etc. Same.
Quotas all look fine.

There's about 20 functions in the project.

```
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env. 
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading... 
[2023-01-17T07:51:09.242Z] RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (5067767843) is greater than 2 GB
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at readFileHandle (node:internal/fs/promises:377:11)
    at async getSourceHash (/Users/adrian/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/cache/hash.js:12:18)
    at async packageSource (/Users/adrian/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/prepareFunctionsUpload.js:61:30)
    at async prepare (/Users/adrian/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/prepare.js:131:36)
    at async chain (/Users/adrian/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:35:9)
    at async deploy (/Users/adrian/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:79:5)

Error: Could not read source directory. Remove links and shortcuts and try again.
```

What file is it referring to?

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new type of log file had been generated which didn't match the current ignore pattern in `firebase.json`. So the log file was being processed during deploy.

Solution: update ignore pattern to cover any `.log` files

`firebase.json`

```
...

"functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": ["node_modules", ".git", "*.log"]
    }
  ]

...
```